# En modo responsive solo puedo dar clic una vez al href de mi submenu

Tags: responsive, href, menu, dropdown

Buen día, buenas tardes, buenas noches y buenas madrugadas, xD les comento que tengo un inconveniente con el submenú de mi página web en modo resposive (al ingresar desde un celular) por ejemplo: al darle clic en "SERVICIOS" se despliega un submenú y al darle clic en "DISEÑO WEB" no me reedirecciona a la página de diseño web, pero si es que realizó está acción desde una computadora de escritorio entonces no tengo ningún problema, les envío mi página web [www.opercomputadoras.com](http://www.opercomputadoras.com) para que puedan ingresar y verificar lo comentado. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Excorpion, buen día, sucede en cualquiera de los submenús de mi página web (la cual les deje el enlace en la pregunta opercomputadoras.com) por ejemplo: cuando ingreses a mi página web en modo responsive (en dispositivos moviles, celulares) le das clic al icono del menú para que se despliegue la lista y en luego le das clic en la etiqueta "Servicios" y luego se desplegará una nueva lista y luego le das clic en "Diseño web" y no te envía a ninguna página y lo mismo sucede con cualquier opción cuando se intenta desde un celular, pero desde la pc de escritorio no hay problemas.

Comment: Comprendo, muchas gracias por la aclaración, en mis próximas publicaciones agregaré las aclaraciones que me comentas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no está en los links, sino en el elemento que tiene encima.

En Modo web y en modo responsive/móvil, el primer link (Menu > Servicios > Diseño Web) tiene el url correcto "diseno-web" (apunta a https://www.opercomputadoras.com/diseno-web), pero en modo responsive, el elemento con clase `dropdown-backdrop` ocupa todo el espacio del menu (supongo que para darle forma/tamaño).

El problema es que queda encima de todo el menú: cuando intentas hacer clic en cualquier lado del menú, el clic se dispara en el `dropdown-backdrop` (y lo unico que hace es cerrar el menú): no hay forma de "tocar" los links con ese div en el camino.

**Solución**: Traté de cambiar el CSS para que el submenu quede "encima" (usando z-index), pero creo que no es posible porque el elemento tiene `display: static`; solo por probar le puse `Display: none` al `dropdown-backdrop` y así los links funcionan. Claro, tienes que probar primero para verificar que ese cambio no afecte nada más, pero al menos ya sabes porqué el link no funciona.

[image: Captura de parte del HTML de https://www.opercomputadoras.com para corregir bug en CSS]

Comment: Hola Roimer, buenas tardes, sinceramente muchas gracias por tu respuesta acertada, también estuve realizando revisiones similares y gracias al curso de Dalto de CSS (Canal de youtube) entendí que había alguna clase (div) que estaba superpuesta al menú pero no lograba identificar cual era, ahora he logrado solucionarlo. Gracias por brindar una respuesta proactiva y a detalle, e inclusive me enviaste una imagen para que no quede ninguna duda jajaja que tengas una feliz navidad!

Comment: De nada! recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta! Cuando hagas preguntas también es buena idea agregar imágenes o fragmentos de código para ayudar a explicar :)

Comment: Hola Roiner, te comento que ahora he logrado solucionarlo pero solo en localhost, cuando lo sube al hosting aún se presenta el problema (a que se deberá? a veces me ha sucedido algo similar y después de unas horas o al día siguiente recien validaba lo realizado). Desde ya muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Es la **caché**: el navegador guarda en caché los archivos de imágenes, CSS, JS, etc, de tu web durante algún tiempo, para que las siguientes veces la página cargue más rápido. Cuando te pase esto, abre la página normalmente y luego presiona `CTRL+F5` (al menos en Chrome y Firefox, no se otros), eso forzará a que cargue la página _completa_ (sin leer de la caché).

Comment: Hola Roimer, buenas tardes, buen dato, es correcto, ya que al día siguiente revise la web nuevamente y ya funciona correctamente, muchas gracias por tu apoyo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer, primero que nada.
Tienes un error con la versión de Boostrap.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> https://www.opercomputadoras.com/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP
> error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Deberías resolver este problema antes de que intentemos algo más.

Comment: Así es, pero cuando le das clic en diseño web debería reedireccionar a la página de diseño web (pero no lo hace en un celular), cuando le das clic a culquiera de las otras opciones debería aparecer en la url el "#" agregado, pero tampoco aparece y esto es porque no está obececiendo al clic que se le realiza a la url y no se cual es el motivo, espero haberme expresado adecuadamente.

Comment: Actualizada la respuesta, no había revisado los errores de tu página.